# OAuth 2.0 Authentication from Azure Function with EventHubs trigger?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to build an Azure Function with an Azure Event Hubs trigger. The [Azure documentation on EventHubTriggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration) says the Function should authenticate to Event Hubs with [SAS keys via a connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string). I have a Service Principal with permission to read from the topic, but my organization does not allow the use of SAS keys, so I can't build a connection string.  Is it possible to authenticate my Service Principal with OAuth 2.0 from an Azure Function?

Comment: Event hubs connection string only supports managed system identity. I don't think you can plugin SP through the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done by using the `HostBuilder` to configure Event Hubs and using the [`AddEventHubClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/blob/5eb8543e47b448eb3b485a571a2ceb1ab404650f/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/Config/EventHubOptions.cs#L89) method to register an existing `EventHubClient` instance that you've initialized using your service principal.

Your entry point would look something like:

```cs
public static Task Main(string[] args)
{    
    // Create and authenticate your EventHubClient.  
    // (this is just a stub to illustrate)

    var eventHubClient = CreateEventHubClientForServicePrincipal();
    
    // Initialize the Functions host and configure the Event Hubs bindings.

    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebJobs(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddEventHubs(options =>
            {
                options.AddEventHubClient(eventHubClient);
            });
        })   
        .Build();

    return host.RunAsync();
}
```

You should be able to write your functions normally at this point and any using the Event Hubs trigger and bindings should make use of that `EventHubClient`.

Brandon Minnick has a nice introduction [here](https://codetraveler.io/2021/02/12/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/) and an end-to-end [example](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/tree/cec71347be100d5d1ab4a3c5b8fd2a5ca0bdf906/GitTrends.Functions), albiet without Event Hubs.  If you're not familiar with authenticating the `EventHubClient`, there are some samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/Rbac/AzureEventHubsSDK/Program.cs#L62).